# Trouble placing wordpress image caption and content on single post page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Working on trying to get single post image and caption above post content in a custom theme. 
Can I get the image caption below the image and remaining content below a new div?

Current code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h3 class="title no-underline">', '</h3>' ); ?>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-content news-item-copy">
        <?php
    $get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
    the_post_thumbnail();
    if(!empty($get_description)){//If description is not empty show the div
    echo '<div class="image-captions">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</div>';
    }
    ?>

        <div class="news-sharing">
        <a class="socialite twitter-share" href="" target="_blank" data-via="" data-text="New Website Launch — " data-url="" data-count="horizontal">Share on Twitter</a>
        <a class="facebook-like socialite" data-href="" target="_blank" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">Like on Facebook</a>
        </div>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

        <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themeName' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

This works in displaying the post image and excerpt but not the image with caption and not the full post text.

Replacing this:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

with:

```
 <?php the_content(); ?>
```

returns the full post content including the image again.

Comment: I would suggest asking your question at the start of... the question post. :)  If we need to search for what the question actually is then it's more difficult to help that person.

Comment: I was able to figure out the first half of the question in obtaining the image/thumbnail caption. Replaced <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' ); ?> with the new code above. Still trying to figure out how to get the post content below the "news-sharing" div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there is nothing special just getting the post object and then its values. post_excerpt are also known as captions.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h3 class="title no-underline">', '</h3>' ); ?>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-content news-item-copy">
        <?php
        if(has_post_thumbnail())
        {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            $thumbnail_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
            $thumbnail_data = get_post($thumbnail_id);
            $caption = $thumbnail_data->post_excerpt;
            if(!empty($caption)){//If description is not empty show the div
                echo '<div class="image-captions">' . $caption . '</div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
        <div class="news-sharing">
            <a class="socialite twitter-share" href="" target="_blank" data-via="" data-text="New Website Launch — " data-url="" data-count="horizontal">Share on Twitter</a>
            <a class="facebook-like socialite" data-href="" target="_blank" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">Like on Facebook</a>
        </div>

        <?php
        echo the_content();
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themeName' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

After this you **don't need to add the featured/thumbnail image to the post content** and it will not appear again in content. I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work when I implemented. I did add some new php to get the image and caption though.